# No space between letter and subscript with TeX Gyre Bonum

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'm using the TeX Gyre Bonum font with xetex, and I've found that the space between a letter and its subscript is very less. This makes things harder to read according to me. How do I fix it?

For example, see the difference between XITS and TeX Gyre Bonum in the example below. In Tex Gyre Bonum, the j is going below the q, which is hard to read.

**Tex Gyre Bonum**

[image: Tex Gyre Bonum]

**XITS**

[image: XITS Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could borrow some code from `mtpro2.sty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Bonum}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`_ \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\futurelet\next\s@@b}%
  \mathcode`\_=\string"8000
  \catcode`_=12
}
\def\s@@b{\ifcat\relax\noexpand\next\expandafter\sb\else
 \expandafter\s@@b@\fi}
\def\s@@b@#1{\sb{\futurelet\next\sb@#1}}
\def\sb@{%
 \ifx\next\@sptoken\def\next@. {\futurelet\next\sb@}\else
  \def\next@.{%
   \ifx\next j\mkern\tw@ mu\else
   \ifx\next f\mkern\tw@ mu\else
   \fi\fi}%
 \fi
 \next@.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$q_j+q_f$

\end{document}
```

Add other kernings if need be, with the same pattern.

[image]

Comment: is `\space@` defined in `mtpro2.sty` ? is it `\@sptoken` ?

Comment: @jfbu Yes, it should be `\@sptoken`

Comment: ``$a^f, b^f, c^f, d^f, e^f, f^f, g^f, h^f, i^f, j^f, k^f, l^f, m^f, n^f, o^f, p^f, q^f, r^f, s^f, t^f, u^f, v^f, w^f, x^f, y^f, z^f$``
``$A^f, B^f, C^f, D^f, E^f, f^f, G^f, H^f, I^f, J^f, K^f, L^f, M^f, N^f, O^f, P^f, Q^f, R^f, S^f, T^f, U^f, V^f, W^f, X^f, Y^f, Z^f$``: appears math kerning is disputable in Bonum Math for `f `.

Comment: @jfbu I agree; some change in the font seems in order.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for explanation of what is happening. jbfu says kerning is disputable for f, but is it characterwise? Or is it for all patterns, because, I now observe that the  kerning is wrong for almost all characters except some like $\Omega$ and other greek letters. So, the above code might not be a fix for everything, and may be too narrow?